# cmake not finding library needed for linking

Tags: oracle, cmake, oracle-call-interface

I am converting a make file into cmake.

```
Make:
ORACLE = -L${ORACLE_HOME}/lib/ -lclntsh \
-I${ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/public 

CMAKE:
include_directories(${ORACLE_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${ORACLE_DIR}/lib)
project(DB_I)
add_executable(DB_I DB_I.c)
target_link_libraries(DB_I LINK_PUBLIC ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} -lclntsh)
install(TARGETS DB_I DESTINATION ${OPEN_FOX_BIN_DIR})

Error:
[ 53%] Linking C executable DB_I
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have ORACLE_HOME pointing to the directory where the files exist.  The compiler is finding the OCI.H file it needs.

```
Directory structure...
ORACLE_HOME
  include
     oci.h
  lib
     libclntsh.so
```

I have even tried moving the libraries into the same directory as the source.
I even copied *clntsh* to  /usr/bin.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: try to specify the head files in the add_executable(), or using set(headers 
   OCI.H
)

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/ibre5041/fb9ce9b71afa50f8fde2 FindOracle.cmake

Comment: Is the lib called `libclntch.so` or `libclntsh.so`? And you may need to delete the CMakeCache.txt file when applying the changes.

Comment: ibre5041 - that seems to do a lot when all i need is to include a library.  Any explanation why you would have to go through all that just to include a lib?   
                      vre - it is libclntsh.so  that was a typo in the directory structure I have now fixed.  I delete my build directory, and reran with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the leading -l in the target_link_libraries

```
target_link_libraries(DB_I LINK_PUBLIC ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} clntsh)
```

Comment: target_link_libraries(${PROJ} LINK_PUBLIC ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} clntsh)  produces the same error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh

Answer (score 0):

Sorry
I just noticed the library file was a link.  And the link was wrong.
I fixed that and all is good.
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is `ORACLE_HOME` is an environment variable.
In Make you get the value wich `${ORACLE_HOME}` but in cmake you must write `$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}`

Also change your

```
link_directories(${ORACLE_DIR}/lib)
```

into

```
link_directories($ENV{ORACLE_DIR}/lib)
```